# Two select picker that doesn't show the selected value in the other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, hide

is there in AngularJS a nice way that it is possible to hide the selected value from the first select picker in the second one?

If I select another value in the first one it need's to be visible again in the second one.

I wrote something with pure javascript that works but it's like magic code that you never want to touch.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: any code/plunker would help, it's a bit vague what you want to achieve

Comment: Maybe ngShow/ngHide (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) are the directives you want? It's hard to tell from your question.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a filter to the second `<select>`. The negative filter's syntax is as follows:

`items | filter: "!somevalue"`

or

`items | filter: "!" + var`

for `var` variable that contains the filtered out string.

So, the full solution looks like so:

```
<select ng-model="select1"
        ng-options = "item for item in items" ng-change="select2 = undefined">
    <option value="">select 1</option>      
</select>

<select ng-model="select2"
        ng-options = "item for item in items | filter: '!' + select1">
    <option value="">select 2</option>
</select>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aU6b92WLzCqhANBgviC1?p=preview)

**EDIT:**

If the order of the selection should not matter, then you could filter as follows:

```
<select ng-model="select1" ng-options="item for item in items | filter: filter1" 
        ng-change="filter2 = select1 ? '!' + select1 : undefined">
  <option value="">select 1</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="select2" ng-options="item for item in items | filter: filter2"
        ng-change="filter1 = select2 ? '!' + select2 : undefined">
  <option value="">select 2</option>
</select>
```

(when filter expression is `undefined` the filter doesn't apply)

[plunker 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/GyLMriwemFqmxII1eMbc?p=preview)

Comment: that's nearly what I meant, is it in your plunker example possible that at the beginning when the two select's load both are filled so that I can choose if I want to start with select1 or select2?

Comment: @user2244925, I updated my answer to include this case

Comment: @user2244925, did my answer address your question?